# How to generate class for JSON c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i am using Newtonsoft.Json for JSON now. Maybe some one know what class i shoud use for this json request?

```
{
"status": 1,
"response": {
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)": {
        "price": 929,
        "quantity": 46
    },
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)": {
        "price": 2716,
        "quantity": 100
    },
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)": {
        "price": 1349,
        "quantity": 345
    },
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear)": {
        "price": 1919,
        "quantity": 143
    },
    "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Well-Worn)": {
        "price": 1135,
        "quantity": 204
    },
    "AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)": {
        "price": 6999,
        "quantity": 14
    },
    "AK-47 | Black Laminate (Field-Tested)": {
        "price": 671,
        "quantity": 83
 }
},
    "time": 1497616580
}
```

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use this classes

```
class StockResponse
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,StockData> response { get; set; }
}

class StockData
{
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize it with

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockResponse>( jsonResponse );
```

Comment: your answer is correct and much like mine, but yours is missing the (weapons) name.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow No, the weapons name is the key value of the response directory

Comment: oh I see, that is a nice and elegant answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Provided that all those AK... classes derive from the same, you should be able to use this (even though it is not recommended, see my edit below):

```
public class Weapon
{
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class AK47AquamarineRevengeFieldTested : Weapon
{
}

public class AK47AquamarineRevengeMinimalWear : Weapon
{
}

// etc., do this for each AK... class

public class Response
{
    public Weapon AK47AquamarineRevengeFieldTested { get; set; }
    public Weapon AK47AquamarineRevengeMinimalWar { get; set; }

    // Add all those weapons here, or use (you need a different JSON result though)
    public IEnumerable<Weapon> Weapons { get ; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
Generally speaking, if you can redesign your code, you would most likely do it this way:

```
public class Weapon
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Weapon> Weapons = new List<Weapon> 
{
   new Weapon { name = "AK47AquamarineRevengeFieldTestet", price = .., quantity = ..},
   new Weapon { name = "AK47AquamarineRevengeMinimalWar", price = .., quantity = ..}, ...
}
```

So you would not create different classes for every rifle, but rather just use one rifle class (`Weapon` in this case) and pass use the rifles name as a property.